# Nested case in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i am very much new to the scala and need to write something like case which i am not understanding to get the right thing:

For e.g I need to convert the below

```
 CASE WHEN ( IS-NULL (Number, 0)) > 0

THEN IS-NULL( (ROUND(number / ((100/number)+1),2) * number), 0 )

ELSE 0 END AS Number_Ratio
```

And I have tried this :

--CREATE DATA FRAME

```
val someDF = Seq(
  (8, "bat"),
  (64, "mouse"),
  (0,   "abc")
).toDF("number", "word")
```

--CASE STATEMENT

```
someDF.select("*").withColumn("NUMBER_RATIO",when (when($"number".isNull,lit(0))>0, when(ROUND($"number" / ((100/$"number"))+1),2* $"number")).isNull,0).otherwise(lit(0)).show()
```

In which I am getting the error :

```
<console>:26: error: too many arguments for method withColumn: (colName: String, col: org.apache.spark.sql.Column)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
```

Cananyone ,please help me,what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide you some tips, you are pretty close on your own :)

1. `IS-NULL(number, 0)` is more readable to type in `Spark` as `coalesce($"number", lit(0))`
2. `ROUND(number, 2)` can be expressed as `pround($"number", 2)` - **this is what you got wrong**
3. `CASE WHEN (condition) THEN (then_clause) ELSE (else_clause)` is `when(condition, then_clause).otherwise(else_clause)`

If you have more questions, feel free to ask in the comments. Good luck.

Comment: Getting this error 

<console>:26: error: overloaded method value / with alternatives:
  (x: Double)Double <and>
  (x: Float)Float <and>
  (x: Long)Long <and>
  (x: Int)Int <and>
  (x: Char)Int <and>
  (x: Short)Int <and>
  (x: Byte)Int
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName)
       someDF.select("*").withColumn("TaxRate",when(coalesce($"number", lit(0))>0, coalesce(round($"number"/((100/$"number")+1),2) * $"number",lit(0)))).otherwise(lit(0)).show()

Comment: @AnkurSharma tip: you have to wrap literal values with `lit()`